# Items can't be added to an array

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to get data from database using the callback method "getAllOrdersByUserId". The results of it are below:

```
[ TextRow {
    DishOrderId: 163,
    BagId: 'BPZDXT68148',
    DateCreated: 2021-05-27T03:55:05.000Z,
    Bags:
     '[{"DishId":43,"DishName":"Kuchvi Biryani","Spicy":2,"UnitPrice":"6.99","Qty":5,"DishTotal":"34.95"}]',
    },
  TextRow {
    DishOrderId: 162,
    BagId: 'BNJENZ08608',
    DateCreated: 2021-05-27T03:46:26.000Z,
    Bags:
     '[{"DishId":41,"DishName":"Dum Biryani","Spicy":2,"UnitPrice":"6.99","Qty":5,"DishTotal":"34.95"}, {"DishId":42,"DishName":"Tysoon Biryani","Spicy":2,"UnitPrice":"6.99","Qty":5,"DishTotal":"34.95"}',
    } ]
```

I am trying to fetch few attributes from the above along with "Bags". But one important thing that i wanted to fetch is Url for the image of the dishes which is not specified in the "Bags" so i am parsing the "Bags" and running through loop to get the "DishId" which will be used to fetched the urls of image from another method with callback name getDishesByDishIds. The DishIds fetched are below:

```
[43]

[41, 42]
```

The method getDIshesByDishIds would fetch below results for above dish Ids when run through for loops:

```
[ TextRow {
    DishId: 43,
   
    DishImageUrl1:
     'http://192.168.86.104:1111/images/dishImageUrl1_1602546024189.JPG'
 } ]

 [ TextRow {
    DishId: 41,
    DishImageUrl1:
     'http://192.168.86.104:1111/images/dishImageUrl1_1602546024190.JPG'
 },
  TextRow {
    DishId: 42,
    DishImageUrl1:
     'http://192.168.86.104:1111/images/dishImageUrl1_1602546024191.JPG'
} ]
```

The real issue i am facing is I am not getting the exact result as per shown below. The main problem i am facing is even though i am able to fetch the url for the dishes , i am not able to add the Urls to the final result as shown below:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "bag": [
        {
            "DishOrderId": 163,
            "BagId": "BPZDXT68148",
            "DateCreated": "2021-05-27T03:55:05.000Z",
            "Bags": [
                {
                    "DishId": 43,
                    "DishName": "Kuchvi Biryani",
                    "Spicy": 2,
                    "UnitPrice": "6.99",
                    "Qty": 5,
                    "DishTotal": "34.95"
                }
            ],
            "Url": ['http://192.168.86.104:1111/images/dishImageUrl1_1602546024189.JPG']
        },
        {
            "DishOrderId": 162,
            "BagId": "BNJENZ08608",
            "DateCreated": "2021-05-27T03:46:26.000Z",
            "Bags": [
                {
                    "DishId": 41,
                    "DishName": "Dum Biryani",
                    "Spicy": 2,
                    "UnitPrice": "6.99",
                    "Qty": 5,
                    "DishTotal": "34.95"
                },
                {
                    "DishId": 42,
                    "DishName": "Tysoon Biryani",
                    "Spicy": 2,
                    "UnitPrice": "6.99",
                    "Qty": 5,
                    "DishTotal": "34.95"
                }
            ],
            "Url": ['http://192.168.86.104:1111/images/dishImageUrl1_1602546024190.JPG',
                    'http://192.168.86.104:1111/images/dishImageUrl1_1602546024191.JPG']
        }
    ]
}
```

The complete code is specified below:

```
 myOrders: (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.body.userId;
    orderStatus = 2;
    getAllOrdersByUserId(userId, orderStatus, (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json({
          success: 0,
          message: "Some other error",
          error: error,
        });
      }
      if (!results) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          success: 0,
          message: "Record not found",
        });
      } else{
        const myOrderArray = []; //this will be new array to store all details including dish Urls
        console.log(results);
        count = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
        const myOrder = {}
        myOrder.DishOrderId = results[i].DishOrderId;
        myOrder.BagId = results[i].BagId;
        myOrder.DateCreated = results[i].DateCreated;
        myOrder.Bags = JSON.parse(results[i].Bags);
        myOrderArray.push(myOrder);

        OrderDishes = JSON.parse(results[i].Bags);
        //for each one of dish in order dishes get the dish id
        let dishId = []
        DishUrls = [];
        countz = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < OrderDishes.length; j++) {
          dishId.push(OrderDishes[j].DishId);

                  //fetch image url for the dish Id fetched
                  //DishUrls = [];
                  getDishesByDishIds(dishId, (error, getDishesByDishIdsResults) => {
                    if (error) {
                      console.log(error);
                      return res.status(500).json({
                        success: 0,
                        message: "Some other error",
                        error: error,
                      });
                    }
                  
                  console.log(getDishesByDishIdsResults); 
                 // DishUrls = [];
                  count2 = 0;
                  for (l = 0; l < getDishesByDishIdsResults.length; l++) {
                    count2++;
                    if(getDishesByDishIdsResults[l].DishImageUrl1 == undefined){
                      if(count2 == getDishesByDishIdsResults.length){
                        //proceed with other steps
                        console.log(DishUrls);
                      }
                    }
                    else{
                      DishUrls.push(getDishesByDishIdsResults[l].DishImageUrl1);                      
                    }
                  }
                });

          countz ++;
          if(countz == OrderDishes.length){
            //do next step
             console.log(DishUrls);
             myOrder.Url = DishUrls; //not working  , coming incorrect
          }
        }   
      }
      
      return res.json({
        success: 1,
        bag: myOrderArray,
       });

      }
   
    });
  },
};
```

Sorry for the long post, but I will really appreciate whoever wanted to help me because I am stuck here since few days.

Comment: can you remove irrelevant code?

Comment: Is the problem that DishImageUrl1 is missing from the second array item (DishId 42) in the second response from getDIshesByDishIds ? Or is that just a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: Actually is getDishesByDishIds going async? That would throw off the whole for loop... You'd need to do some immediate-async-callback-magic stuff to make that work...

Comment: @ryancdotnet , yes you are correct, it was a typo, I have fixed that. And I guess you are correct, I w was wanting some immediate-async-callback-magic stuff. Can you please help me to achieve it?

Comment: @Skarlinski I guess there is no irrelevant code. If i remove some it will become very hard to understand how the loops are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Disclaimer

Forgive me... I wrote this late night after an already LONG day at work...

I have no confidence in this code. It is untested, and is written very poorly. Probably won't work.

But...

I'm hopeful it gets you in the right direction at least.

## Refactored Code

```
myOrders: (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.body.userId;
    let orderStatus = 2;

    getAllOrdersByUserId(userId, orderStatus, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).json({
                success: 0,
                message: "Some other error",
                error: error,
            });

            return;
        }

        if (!results) {
            res.status(404).json({
                success: 0,
                message: "Record not found",
            });

            return;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            
            (() => {
                let currentOrder = results[i];
                currentOrder.Bags = JSON.parse(currentOrder.Bags);

                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    let dishIds = [];

                    for (let j = 0; j < currentOrder.Bags.length; j++) {
                        dishIds.push(currentOrder.Bags[j].DishId);
                    }

                    (() => {
                        return new Promise((innerResolve, innerReject) => {
                            getDishesByDishIds(dishIds, (error, getDishesByDishIdsResults) => {
                                let dishUrlResults = [];

                                if (error) {
                                    innerReject("An error occurred during retrieval of the dish image urls");
                                    return;
                                }
                
                                for (let l = 0; l < getDishesByDishIdsResults.length; l++) {
                                    if (getDishesByDishIdsResults[l].DishImageUrl1 != undefined) {
                                        dishUrlResults.push(getDishesByDishIdsResults[l].DishImageUrl1);
                                    }
                                }

                                innerResolve(dishUrlResults);
                            });
                        });
                    })()
                    .then((urlResults) => {
                        currentOrder.Url = urlResults;
                        resolve();
                    })
                    .catch((innerPromiseError) => {
                        reject(innerPromiseError);
                    });
                });
            })()
            .then(() => {
                res.json({
                    success: 1,
                    bag: results,
                });
            })
            .catch((promiseError) => {
                //Could not complete the request
                console.log(promiseError);

                res.status(500).json({
                    success: 0,
                    message: "Some other error",
                    error: error,
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I ran your code but i dont see the Url(2 urls)  for the second dish order. Can you see if you can fix it. Actually i also got the error message of unhandled promise rejection in my console. Also an error initially as "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Comment: Never mind, i was able to fix it by doing a count in the outer .then statement. And thank you very very much in helping me out in this. Really appreciated.

Comment: Glad to have at least gotten you closer! The magic part has to do with closure and the fact that you were needing to call an async function inside of a for loop. For that to work, you have to handle the closure part of the equation by using immediate function calls to immediately resolve the values you need in the for loop first. Then you needed to handle the results that come back from the async fn calls, and send a response back when it was finally appropriate to do so. In reading my code now, I can see where I left a few bugs in the logic, but it sounds like you figured it out. :)